# How does spring session create the session table?

Tags: spring-session

I am using spring boot and trying to import spring session.

All I have done is add one single line to the application.yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: xx
    url: jdbc:postgresql://c:5432/dbname?schema=public
    username: pg

  session:
    store-type: jdbc
```

Then I found that two tables `spring_session` and `spring_session_attributes` auto generated in my database. This is expected except one thing: these two tables are generated in a different table schema. However, the tables generated by jpa(hibernate) are being put in another schema.

I tired to dig into the source codes, however, I cannot find the codes which are calling the `org/springframework/session/jdbc/xx-h2.sql` to create the table.

What's the magic?